# Going crazy. Spring 3.0.x Hibernate 3.6.5 JPA - Unable to configure EntityManagerFactory

Tags: hibernate, spring, gwt, jpa

I've been going crazy for the last several hours.  I simply cannot configure Spring, Hibernate, with JPA.

I have a default GWT project.  The only non default thing is I've decided to use JSON for communicating with the server both ways.  I'm using jax-rs (jersey) to do this.

My war directory looks like this BEFORE attempting to add spring or hibernate to the project:

- war
- war/project-name
- war/WEB-INF
- war/WEB-INF/classes (and subdirectories)
- war/lib
- war/lib/asm-3.1.jar
- war/lib/flexjson-2.1.jar
- war/lib/gwt-servlet.jar
- war/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.7.1.jar
- war/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.7.1.jar
- war/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.7.1.jar
- war/lib/jackson-xc-1.7.1.jar
- war/lib/jersey-client-1.7.jar
- war/lib/jersey-core-1.7.jar
- war/lib/jersey-json-1.7.jar
- war/lib/jersey-server-1.7.jar
- war/lib/jettison-1.1.jar
- war/lib/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar
- war/web.xml

Not so bad, 13 JARS and a single XML file containing a few lines.  It's pretty compact, I have the JSON going back and forth as expected.  Perfect.  Now all I have to do is add the ORM.  I've used Spring and hibernate in past projects but I've never really configured them.

The problem is, how do you find out how to configure them?  If you google it, you will find millions of tutorials (most of them out of date).  The hibernate tutorial is great and I'm almost 100% certain I could get plain hibernate working easily (in fact I did a long time ago).  But I want to stick with industry conventions and use Hibernate with Spring and JPA.

I found this tutorial here, which seems to be up to date:
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/05/gwt-2-spring-3-jpa-2-hibernate-35.html

But I'm going in circles.  Problem after problem.  After I start the GWT app I get this:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
[WARN] Server class 'javax.validation.Validation' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
   [WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:/Users/jose/springsource/sts-2.5.2.SR1/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.3.0.r36v201105191508/gwt-2.3.0/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar' to the web app classpath for this session
   For additional info see: file:/Users/jose/springsource/sts-2.5.2.SR1/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.3.0.r36v201105191508/gwt-2.3.0/doc/helpInfo/webAppClassPath.html
Starting Jetty on port 8888
   [WARN] Failed startup of context com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload@48270dbf{/,/Users/jose/workspace/MyProject/war}
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: MyPersistenceUnit] Unable to configure EntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:543)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:513)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:463)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:115)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:667)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:500)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1055)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:804)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:309)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: MyPersistenceUnit] Unable to configure EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:378)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:48)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:92)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationActivator.applyDDL(BeanValidationActivator.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyBeanValidationConstraintsOnDDL(Configuration.java:1704)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyConstraintsToDDL(Configuration.java:1654)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1445)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1375)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildMappings(Ejb3Configuration.java:1519)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EventListenerConfigurator.configure(EventListenerConfigurator.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:1100)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:366)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationActivator.applyDDL(BeanValidationActivator.java:118)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to build the default ValidatorFactory
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyDDL(TypeSafeActivator.java:109)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to find a default provider
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:264)
    at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:380)
    ... 51 more
   [WARN] Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: MyPersistenceUnit] Unable to configure EntityManagerFactory:
javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to find a default provider
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:264)
    at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyDDL(TypeSafeActivator.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationActivator.applyDDL(BeanValidationActivator.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyBeanValidationConstraintsOnDDL(Configuration.java:1704)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyConstraintsToDDL(Configuration.java:1654)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1445)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1375)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildMappings(Ejb3Configuration.java:1519)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EventListenerConfigurator.configure(EventListenerConfigurator.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:1100)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:366)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:48)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:92)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:543)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:513)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:463)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:115)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:667)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:500)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1055)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:804)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:309)
```

Here is what my war directly looks like currently:

- war
- war/project-name
- war/WEB-INF
- war/WEB-INF/classes (and subdirectories)
- war/META-INF/persistence.xml
- war/lib
- war/lib/antlr-2.7.6.jar
- war/lib/aopalliance.jar
- war/lib/asm-3.1.jar
- war/lib/c3p0-0.9.1.jar
- war/lib/commons-collections-3.1.jar
- war/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
- war/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar
- war/lib/flexjson-2.1.jar
- war/lib/gwt-servlet.jar
- war/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
- war/lib/hibernate3.jar
- war/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.7.1.jar
- war/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.7.1.jar
- war/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.7.1.jar
- war/lib/javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar
- war/lib/jackson-xc-1.7.1.jar
- war/lib/jersey-client-1.7.jar
- war/lib/jersey-core-1.7.jar
- war/lib/jersey-json-1.7.jar
- war/lib/jersey-server-1.7.jar
- war/lib/jettison-1.1.jar
- war/lib/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar
- war/lib/jta-1.1.jar
- war/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar
- war/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.16-bin.jar
- war/lib/org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- war/lib/org.springframework.asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- war/lib/org.springframework.aspects-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- war/lib/org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- war/lib/org.springframework.context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- war/lib/org.springframework.context.support-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- war/lib/org.springframework.core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- war/lib/org.springframework.expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- war/lib/org.springframework.instrument-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- war/lib/org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- war/lib/org.springframework.jdbc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- war/lib/org.springframework.jms-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- war/lib/org.springframework.orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- war/lib/org.springframework.oxm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- war/lib/org.springframework.test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- war/lib/org.springframework.transaction-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- war/lib/org.springframework.web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- war/lib/org.springframework.web.portlet-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- war/lib/org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- war/lib/org.springframework.web.struts-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- war/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
- war/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
- war/applicationContext.xml
- war/web.xml

Here's my web.xml

```
<web-app>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Servlets -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.jose.server</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Default page to serve -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>MyProject.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Here's my persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="MyPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/blah"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>

            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="3000"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

1. Does anyone know why I'm encountering the error above?
2. Can someone refer me to a very simple (AND update to date!) tutorial on how to configure these frameworks?  It's not that I don't understand hibernate.  I've used it for the last 3 years (although only heavily in the past few months in the form of Grails).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the application is looking for a [validation provider](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html_single/). Add [hibernate-validator 4.x](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator/download.html) to your classpath.

Comment: Thanks gouki.  I wish I had read your response earlier.  I just spent the last several hours searching the internet.  I wound up ripping out spring and jpa and just using plain Hibernate.  Finally, when even the basic hibernate example would not work (due to issue with Validator) I found some obscure post on the internet which included the 2 jars I had to add. Do you have any idea why my project setup causes this issue? Is it GWT? Jersey?  Thanks.  Now that I finally have a single record in the database after about 6 hours I'm afraid to go back and try Spring.

Comment: What are the two jars you added? The validator exception was thrown by Hibernate and not because of Spring.

Comment: [Hibernate Validator](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/4.0.2.GA)

Answer (score 1):

Which version of GWt you are using? GWT2.3and higher versions has validator implementation. You need to add them explicetely in classpath.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error message:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myName' ...: 
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: 
>   [PersistenceUnit: MyPersistenceUnit] Unable to configure EntityManagerFactory"

Turned out that one of the newly added Entity class did not have a primary key `@Id` defined. Hope that helps someone in future.

Comment: I am getting the same error. But it's because of `@Service("personService")
public class PersonServiceJpa implements PersonService {...}`. The partial error reads: `Error creating bean with name 'personService': Injection of persistence methods failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError` Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I give more details at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734978/what-is-happening-inside-applicationcontext-xml

Answer (score 0):

"If you don't want to use hibernate bean validation, you can add this
line to your hibernate `persistence.xml` file:

```
  <validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>"
```

This will solve the problem without adding the classpaths.

source: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.org.google.gwt/60720